# Admob Interstitial Ad doesn't hide status bar

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

Screen

[image: 1]

Admob Interstitial Ad is showing but the status bar isn't hidden on some devices.

Comment: Which devices? Do those devices have notches? Are the notches "hidden" from the settings?

Comment: Got same bug on Huawei ANE-LX1 and OnePlus 8T (showing/hiding notches from settings does not change the result)